# "URI is not hierarchical" + private key

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, jsch

I just started using Jsch for an SSH connection in my Java program (made for Windows 7). I am running into an issue incorporating a private key into my program. I use the following code:

```
URL keyFileURL = Main.class.getResource("auth/public_key_1");
URI keyFileURI = keyFileURL.toURI();
jsch.addIdentity(new File(keyFileURI).getAbsolutePath());
```

Where "auth" is a folder in the same package. The good news is that everything works fine when running it in Eclipse, however it fails when running it as a jar. The error that is given is: "IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical".

I know the error has to do with pathnames and using URI as a File, but I don't know how else to reference a resource within the jar file without externally importing it (i.e. from file in same folder as jar) AND still have it compatible with Jsch.

Can someone help me with the code to appropriately reference a resource in the program and still have Jsch accept it as a key.

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Update:

I tried @bmargulies recommended code:

```
    String authfile;

     URL resUrl = Resources.getResource(Main.class, "auth/public_key_1");
     File tempFile = File.createTempFile("key", ".key");
     ByteSink sink = Files.asByteSink(tempFile);
     try (OutputStream os = sink.openStream()) {
         Resources.copy(resUrl, os);
         authfile = os.toString();
         jsch.addIdentity(authfile);
     }
```

But it gives me error: "java.io.FileOutputStream (The system cannot find the file specified)". Is there anything I should fix in the code or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you read a resource. You can't get a `File` for a resource, only a stream. The URL's for resources don't correspond to files.

If jsch can handle a stream, pass it the results of `getResourceAsStream`.

If jsch can handle an array of bytes, pass it the results of reading the stream into an array of bytes.

If it must have a file, create a temp file.

In the third case, I'd incorporate Guava and write the code like:

```
URL resUrl = Resources.getResource(Main.class, "auth/public_key1");
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("key", ".key");
ByteSink sink = Files.asByteSink(tempFile);
try (OutputStream os = sink.openStream()) {
    Resources.copy(resUrl, os);
}
```

and pass the `File`'s path to jsch.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Jsch takes a String when dealing with private keys (plz don't ask me why). I tried your sample code (incorporated Guava) but I'm running into trouble with the "createByteSink" in that it gives an undefined error.

Comment: My bad, it's 'asByteSink'. Edited.

Comment: Sorry, one last issue. "createTempFile" is also giving me an undefined error. Should i actually create a method for this?

Comment: Update (didn't edit for others). Rename "createTempFile" to "File.createTempFile"

Comment: Tried the code, unfortunately it gives me a "System cannot find the file specified" error. Will look through it some more to see if I can get it to work. Do you know of anything else that might work? Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: Interesting enough, if I purposefully change the filename to something incorrect, it gives me a different error: "resource... relative to Main not found". So at least it is getting the right file.

Comment: What line does it get the exception on? THe call to jsch, or some of the code I posted?

Comment: It looks like it's failing on the call to Jsch due to FIleOutputStream: "com.jcraft.jasch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFOundException : java.io.FileOutputStream (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Well, if it's complaining about output, you've gotten past the key problem.

Comment: I tried using getResourceAsStream, BufferedReader, and InputStreamReader. As you said, I think the first part of getting the key is solved, now Jsch doesn't want to take it as an identity. Perhaps it is expecting an actual file path? I have no idea. At this point I am tempted just to hardcode the password instead of key authentication, but I know it's a bad idea. Any other ideas that might work?

Comment: It turns out that jsch can also take it in Bytes. Any sample code that would be handy to convert the file to Byte. Will try various examples on Google, but figured I'd ask and save hours of time searching.

Comment: Guava resources has a method to deliver byte[]

Comment: Thanks, creating temporary file using Guava actually worked!